# How can I console.log an individual attribute from a JSON payload object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to console.log some JSON values from an OpeanSea api call payload.
I can successfully hit the end point as seen in the console
when I run this:

```
await fetch(`https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collections?asset_owner=${currentAccount}&offset=0&limit=300`, options)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => console.log("collection owned by current address", response))
```

but when I try to log only one attribute from the response object:

```
await fetch(`https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collections?asset_owner=${currentAccount}&offset=0&limit=300`, options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(({ assetts }) => {
    assetts.forEach((attributes) => {
      console.log(attributes.name)
    })
  })
```

I see

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
```

Is

```
assetts
```

an arbitrary name to iterate through? I think this is what i dont understand

Comment: how does the response obj look like

Comment: Is `assetts` a property that exists on the object? Because the error indicates it does not. Also, the correct spelling of the word would be "assets" with one "t".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know the structure of json and target the required attributes. Like in your case its collections array which is array of object and each object contains name key so you can target key like:

```
await fetch(`https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collections?asset_owner=${currentAccount}&offset=0&limit=300`, options)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((assetts) => {
      assetts.collections.forEach((attributes) => {
        console.log(attributes.name);
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log({ error });
    });
```

In your first then block you should have to return response after parsing it, if you want to use the parsed data in next then block.

Tip: It is a good practice if you also handle error by putting catch block after then block.